# BackgroundColor doesn't work in NSTableCellView

Tags: xcode, cocoa, background, nstableview, nstablecellview

Why the backgroundColor doesn't work with owner:self.table? It only works with owner:self, however, with the second option -awakeFromNib is called many times.

setStringValue works with both options.

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSTableCellView *cell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MainCell" owner:self.table];
    [cell.textField setStringValue:@"FunWithFlags"]
    cell.layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor greenColor] CGColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The owner param expects the owner object of the NIB which should be loaded and instantiated to create a new view with the supplied identifier.
The table object self.table is not the owner of any nib hence it does not return any view.